# Swift Core Data, record won't delete, even with save()

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm attempting to delete an object from the core data in swift. I am able to save objects fine, however, the delete does not work. I am calling both .delete(object) and then .save() which run correctly and have verified that the object being fed in is valid, however the object never get's deleted despite no errors coming back from the code.

Here's my save function, when false is provided as a parameter, it should delete the record:

```
func SaveFighter(_ save:Bool)
{
    // get the (only) managed context...
    let managedContext = DataBaseHelper.persistentContainer.viewContext
    // ... get the Entity (table) description for the only entity [SavedFighter]...
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "SavedFighter", in: managedContext)!
    // ... retrieve the associated Maanaged Object for this entity
    let savedFighter = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

    // put Fighter object members into matching attributes in the Managed Object
    savedFighter.setValue(self.nickname, forKeyPath: "nickname")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.first_name, forKeyPath: "first_name")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.last_name, forKeyPath: "last_name")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.weight_class, forKeyPath: "weight_class")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.statid, forKeyPath: "statid")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.losses, forKeyPath: "losses")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.draws, forKeyPath: "draws")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.wins, forKeyPath: "wins")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.id, forKeyPath: "id")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.title_holder, forKeyPath: "title_holder")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.fighter_status, forKeyPath: "fighter_status")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.rank, forKeyPath: "rank")
    savedFighter.setValue(self.thumbnail, forKeyPath: "thumbnail")

    if (save) // save this fighter in DB
    {
        // need to account for exceptions if saving fails
        do
        {
            // commit the prepares Managed Object in the Managed Context
            try managedContext.save()
            // set flag to say the object has been saved to DB
            print("Fighter: \(first_name) was ADDED to the Bookmarks Database!")
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Could not save \(first_name) \(error)")
        }
    }
    else  // delete this fighter from bookmarks DB
    {
        // create a fetchrequest to associate with the SavedFighter entity
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SavedFighter")
        // set a predicate (query) to only select a unique record based on id
        print("Attempting to delete record with ID: " + String(self.id))

        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", String(self.id))   // use id because it is unique

        do
        {
            // run the query to get the resultset (can be more than one record)
            let resultData = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [SavedFighter]
            print("Found \(resultData.count) records to delete...")
            // iterate through all the found records...
            for object in resultData
            {   //... to delete each record
                print(object)
                managedContext.delete(object)
                try managedContext.save() // commit changes to context
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Could not find any records to delete...")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting when Fighter.SaveFighter(false) is called for the object to be deleted from the DB, however it remains no matter what.

From the debug, I've got the following prints:

```
Attempting to delete record with ID: 1161
Found 1 records to delete...
<SavedFighter: 0x61800028c170> (entity: SavedFighter; id: 0xd000000000bc0000 <x-coredata://64D235C6-E488-4EC1-ADA6-9F4B7CBCAB0D/SavedFighter/p47> ; data: <fault>)
```

So the object is clearly being retrieved from the DB successfully, but still won't delete.

Comment: I suspect "accidental" call to SaveFighter with boolean argument true just after calling. it with false.

Comment: It remains where? In memory, or in the results of a future fetch request?